# PHP tags and quotes in variables causing syntax/parse errors

Tags: php, parsing, variables, syntax, syntax-error

These lines are causing a syntax/parse error, and I'm not sure how to fix it.  I'm pretty sure it's either the `<?php` and `?>` tags, or the single quotes.  Any ideas?

```
$data = '<?php
    $title = "'. $name. '";
    $keywords = "'. $title. ','. $developer. '";
    $description = "How to install '. $title. ' for PC and Mac.";

    include('templates/modheader.php');
    include('templates/modfooter.php');
    ?>';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's more likely to be the fact that you're not escaping the `'` around your included filenames

Comment: Consider a [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/HEREDOC) string.

Comment: @arielcr It's a variable to create a file.   Yes, the formatting is a bit strange.

Comment: The use of `$title` is confusing here.

Comment: @Phil I combined two files.  I still need to delete some things.  The post example is quite confusing.

Comment: Nothing about this looks like anything a sane person should ever actually put into production. Stop. Rethink. Rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
include('templates/modheader.php');
include('templates/modfooter.php');
```

is the culprit: You mix single quotes. SImply use

```
include("templates/modheader.php");
include("templates/modfooter.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
include('templates/modheader.php');
include('templates/modfooter.php');
```

should be

```
include("templates/modheader.php");
include("templates/modfooter.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

For large blocks of string data, I highly recommend the [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) / [`NOWDOC`](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax. You can combine that with `sprintf` to inject values

```
$template = <<<'_PHP'
<?php
$title = '%s';
$keywords = $title . ',%s';
$description = "How to install $title for PC and Mac.";

include 'templates/modheader.php';
include 'templates/modfooter.php';
?>
_PHP;

$data = sprintf($template, $name, $developer);
```